# Sympy Collect() in trig expression

Tags: python, sympy

I’m new to sympy and I’m having trouble using collect() inside a trigonometric function.  I am not using simplify() or trigsimp() because my actual expression is more complicated and they oversimplify it.  I am trying to simplify it step by step into a particular form.  Why doesn’t collect(sin(x*y+x*z),x) group the x terms?   Thanks.

```
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')

print(collect(sin(2*x + 3*x),x))
sin(5*x)  #Works

print(collect(x*y + x*z, x))
x*(y + z)  #Works

print(collect(sin(x*y+x*z),x))
sin(x*y + x*z)  #Doesn’t work - Expected sin(x(y+z))
```

Comment: The `collect` function assumes that your expression is a top-level polynomial. You can use e.g. `factor_terms` to apply this kind of simplification recursively into subexpressions.

Comment: That's just what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply a function to arguments of an expression and the function doesn't have a `deep` option, you can try create a lambda that will apply the function to an arbitrary expression and use that with `bottom_up`:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import *
>>> bottom_up(sin(x+x*y), lambda e: collect(e, x))
sin(x*(y + 1))
```

A targeted replacement would also work:

```
>>> sin(x+x*y).replace(lambda e: e.is_Add and e.has(x), lambda e: collect(e,x))
sin(x*(y + 1))
```

Comment: Neat approach. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

**For Collect:**

> user is
> expected to provide an expression is an appropriate form. This makes
> :collect more predictable as there is no magic happening behind the
> scenes.

So, I guess collect have some trouble reading the expression you are giving. Since you says you want step to step answer, I think you can use temp variables to pass the inner expression.

```
t = collect(x*y + x*z, x)
print(collect(sin(t),x))
```

This will give you `sin(x*(y + z))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I see that it works in the case I presented but in my actual application, I'm not building the sin argument from scratch.  It comes from other trig simplifications.   So I'm not sure how to apply this solution.